# How to recover an old Stellar account?

Tags: stellar-core, accounts

I have tried to recover the account at https://launch.stellar.org/#/recovery with a username and recovery code, but I get the following message: Recovery disabled. Account can't be recovered by Stellar Development Foundation.

[image: Screenshot of message "Recovery Disabled"]

Is anyone able to help with recovering an old Stellar account?